# What Is Associativity in Composition

Tags: functions, category-theory

[Link to Original Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594658/what-is-a-morphism?noredirect=1#comment3247783_1594658)

I never thought of this until recently when I began learning about categories.  In the past, with function composition, I understand associativity as follows.  Suppose that $(a, b)$ is in the graph of $f:  A \to B$; $(b, c)$ in the graph of $g:  B \to C$; $(c, d)$ in $h:  C \to D$.

\begin{align}
(h \circ g)(f(a)) & = (h \circ g)(b) = h(c) = d \\
h((g \circ f)(a)) & = h(c) = d
\end{align}

Hence, there is only one "path" in the sense that $a \mapsto b \mapsto c \mapsto d$.  But apparently if $f, g, h$ are not well-defined functions, associativity can still hold as long as there are elements taking me from $a$ to $d$.  For example:

$$\begin{matrix}
a & \longrightarrow & b_1 & \longrightarrow & c_1 & \longrightarrow & d \\
& f & & g & & h & & \\
a & \longrightarrow & b_2 & \longrightarrow & c_2 & \longrightarrow & d
\end{matrix}$$

I just want to make sure that I am understanding this correctly.  Associativity allows more than one "path"?

Comment: Associativity is a purely algebraic property. It doesn't matter what the operation actually is, though of course the operation itself must be well defined. Say $foo#bar=bop$, $bop#bor=boop$, $bar#bor=flop$,$foo#flop=boop$...Then $(foo#bar)#bor=foo#(bar#bor)$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: The question is very imprecise. Do you want to know how to argue that the composition of relations is associative? Or is this a question about more general categories?

Comment: In a category, composition of arrows (morphisms) is defined without reference to elements or graphs, and is associative by definition. Composition can be defined for relations as well as functions, and then it is associative, but if you are following elements there may be more than one path if I understand your meaning correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, associativity allows more than one "path" in the sense of your question.

Basically you try to replace *functions* to *relations* and wonder if their composition is still associative. And, yes, it is.

And thus the sets form another category (mostly called $\mathbf{Rel}$) where the morphisms are relations.

Comment: TY all ....  This settles my question.